# Check C# query string for SQL injection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-injection

I was given a project in which the developer at the time did not parameterize SQL queries, but simply concatenated the values provided by the user. Now I was given the task to make the application immune to SQL injection attakings with as little effort as possible. A lot of SQL queries are distributed throughout the code, so that a postprocessing of all queries is almost impossible. It would cost me many months of work.

The advantage is that all queries are executed by one method. My solution now would be to check the query string in this one method, in which all queries run, for semicolons and 'GO' keywords before executing it. At this point it should be mentioned that I can guarantee that exactly one query is always executed. If there is more than one semicolon or a 'GO' statement in the string, I refuse the execution to the database and abort the process.

My question now: Does anyone have a better suggestion to solve the problem? How would you tackle the problem here?

Thank you.

Comment: Rewrite the code and do it properly by binding values to placeholders.

Comment: That's funny. That would take years.

Comment: @Shawn's response is the only **real, viable** solution ...

Comment: `Now I was given the task to make the application immune to SQL injection attakings with as little effort as possible.` If you want immunity, you **need** parameterised queries. Any other approach is breakable. Can you get _some_ of the way by white / black listing - sure. But that isn't immunity.

Comment: Your problem is that you cannot detect all possible SQL manipulations. If I put the string "' OR 1=1 OR SomeField = 'whatever" then I bypass your where constraint with my 1=1.

Comment: `I asked cleanly and a comment like "rewrite the code..." is not helpful` Sometimes hard things need to be done. If you want to reduce your chances of lung cancer, you need to stop smoking. Doctors telling people to stop smoking, even though it is very hard, is not being unhelpful. It is telling them something that they should seriously consider doing.

Comment: @Ali - Your question: "Does anyone have a better suggestion to solve the problem? How would you tackle the problem here?" -- Shawns answer: "Rewrite the code and do it properly by [...]". -- Clear answer to a clear question. -- preventing SQL injection is a solved problem. Doing *anything* other than the known and tested method of using parameters bears the risk of being circumventable. You might not like it and it probably is a lot of work, but it's also the only way to be sure to be save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't think that doing anything apart from using exactly the feature of SQL Server that prevents it (parameterized query) will help you. You can to some extent try to prevent injection from happening, removing obvious injections vectors, buy you can never be sure. Hackers are inventive guys :)

So if you want a robust solution, I advise you to rewrite to parametereized queries. It's very easy to do with e.g. Dapper. But I understand the amount of code you have can make it very time consuming, but there is unfortunately no way around it.